# Hooking the PHP Runtime

Tags: php, model-view-controller, configuration

Is there any way in php.info (or other config file) for me to indicate a script to be run every single time PHP is invoked?

I'm interested in mapping HTTP requests for a particular page to a Controller class representing that page, similar to how a lot of MVC framework (like CI) work.

For instance, the user clicks a link that should map to /webroot/some/url/widget.php, but rather the /webroot/app/mvc/controllers/WidgetController.php class is what gets invoked instead.

To do this, I figure MVC framework like CI have figured out a way to "hook" the PHP Runtime by running a script that runs and says "oh, the request is for widget.php, but we want to actually run the WidgetController.php object."

Any ideas/thoughts/suggestions/concerns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be the wrong trail here. Zend Framework and other Frameworks I know use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or similar techniques to redirect requests, which are then processed by some kind of [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

This means that your request to example.org/mypage is being redirected by Apache (not PHP) to myfrontcontroller.php, which then decides how to handle the incoming request.

Comment: Thanks @Philipp! So does this mean that all GET and POST data would also be sent to myfrontcontroller.php as well?

Comment: Yes. With mod_rewrite, you can decide what will be redirected to your front controller. You could even decide to use more than one front controller, for example by specifying a rule that redirects all requests to example/foo/... to example/controllers/foocontroller.php and all requests to example/bar to example/controllers/barcontroller.php.

Comment: Symfony2 implements exactly the request flow Phillipp described and there's a nice visualization of it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-under-the-hood

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the **php.ini** option [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.sect.data-handling).

Answer (score 0):

You need a router, and apache mod_rewrite or equivalent. You set up mod_rewrite to send all requests to a single file, such as /index.php. The router then looks at the request URL and determines which controller file to load and which method to call. Pretty much any MVC framework has this functionality built-in, and they all work pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

An `index.php` in the webroot should be sufficient, the path will be passed as the server variable `PATH_INFO`.

Answer (score 0):

See [`https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

Edit: My answer is simply meant to be an FYI. As others have mentioned, mod_rewrite is the accepted way to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @Alex - can you confirm whether this mod_rewrite method also "forwards" on GET and POST data to the controller class as well? Thanks for the helpful answers!

Comment: Generally, yes. (Note that you can design the rules not to, if that's your preference.) Normally, you'll have a rule that says "send everything to index.php" and then index.php will look at PATH_INFO to figure out what to do.